# Automatically extend discrete xticks when using dates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

When defining xticks in PGFplots one can say something like:

```
xtick={0,2,...10},
```

to achieve ticks at 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10

My x-axis has the date coordiantes definded in the pgf manual, however i cannot find a solution for the automatic completion of the xtick function like above.

Writting something like:

```
xtick={1972-01-01,1974-01-01,...,2014-01-01},
```

results in:

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
```

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `xticklabel` key to append `-01-01` after every tick, and then use `xtick={1972,1974,...,2014}` for the year numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xticklabel style={rotate=90,/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={},fixed},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}-01-01},
            xtick={1972,1974,...,2014},
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {
                (1972,1)
                (1982,4)
                (2000,3)
                (2012,8)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not 100% what I needed as now I cannot calculate anymore using the real timestamps, however that seems to be a good workaround for me so far, thank you

Comment: @SRel I was afraid that you wanted to do something like that, maybe if you un-accept my answer and place a bounty you could attract some more attention. I am willing to delete my answer if you want.